# iTunes: bulk edit/update paths to music files

Tags: macos, itunes

I had to change a path from `/a/b/c/d/<hundreds of files>.mp3` to `/a/b/c/<hundreds of files>.mp3`

Is there some way to bulk update this information?

I'm using iTunes 11 on Mountain Lion

Comment: How many tracks are we talking about here? The easiest thing would be to change back the path. If this is not feasible for you, there might be other solutions. How familiar are you with Terminal?

Comment: Are you letting iTunes organise your files or are you manually doing this?

Comment: Mark: I'm not letting iTunes organize my files.  

patrix: There are hundreds of tracks and I rather not revert to the old path.  I'm very familiar with Terminal.