# Bulk reformatting of purchased Music tracks?

Tags: audio, music, mp3

We have imported many songs from our dozens of CDs into Music.app.  To be "nice guys," we have been slowly replacing them with tracks purchased from Apple—374 so far.

Unfortunately (for one example), a purchased track that is 7.6 MB is 1.9 MB in MP3, and there is no detectable difference in the sound.  (Maybe I could buy some expensive speakers and give up portability, but that's not going to happen!)  Apply that proportion to 374 and there's a 2.6 GB waste of space.  Not a problem for the 1TB laptop, but one of our iPads and both iPhones are already too full to do updates without removing Music or Photos (and we only sync a small part of the music to them).

If both versions are displayed in the library, Music refuses to play the smaller one (double-click on it in the library view—nothing happens.  If the purchased file is moved to trash and the trash emptied, Music still won't play the other until the purchased one is also hidden.

**Is there any simple way to automate that process for all 374 purchased tracks?**  (To have the much smaller MP3 be the one Music plays instead of the AAC?)

Similar but not a duplicate (and not answered) is [iTunes: bulk edit/update paths to music files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96954/itunes-bulk-edit-update-paths-to-music-files)

Since it was asked:  Purchase a song, you download an AAC (.4a)
If you ask Music to creat an MP3 version, the result is half the size and **IS** in the library, right next to the  AAC and is half the size. If I open the AAC or the MP3 in Amadeus, and then "Save As" MP3, unless I change name or directory, it replaces the other MP3 and is about one-quarter the size of the AAC.  Click the play button in Mucis next to the MP3 and it plays the AAC file instead (as shown by the animation next to it).  Move the AAC to the trash and empty; same behavior—it streams from the store, but of course not if you are off-line.  Select the AAC and try to select "delete" and the option instead is to hide it.  Only then does it play the MP3 instead of the AAC.

As for whether or not I own the music, that is unimportant.  Some I own, some I don't.  The latter is one reason for buying it eventually.  Another reason is that the sound quality suffers when digitizing cassettes or vinyl.  Sometimes, even abused CDs have quality issues.  But none of that is relevant to the need to reduce file size.

Comment: Why would you be re-purchasing what you've already purchased?

Comment: Nobody said anything about re-purchasing.  In fact, you can't "re-purchase."  If you try, you are only offered the chance to re-download.  I thought I was fairly clear in saying I want to replace 374 local copies of purchased AAC format with MP3 format to free up 2.6 gigabytes of space.  Their status of "purchased" and their metadata does not change.

Comment: "We have imported many songs from our dozens of CDs into Music.app.  To be "nice guys," we have been slowly replacing them with tracks purchased from Apple".  So you bought CD's and now you're buying AM tracks?  If that's not what you meant, you will understand the confusion.

Comment: Some CDs were purchased, some were free, and at least one I am sure is bootleg.   Some tracks are transferred from vinyl or from Youtube.  To "be nice" to the copyright owner, I look up one of two a month to purchase the digital copy.  And occasionally I hear something I like that I don't have and purchase that.  The issue is that Apple's AAC format is not only less portable, but wastes space without any sound quality improvement that I can detect.  The purchase _does_ give me the benefit of more metadata and the album art.

Comment: There’s a couple things that’s not clear here.  A) Music “refusing” to play MP3 vs. AAC and B) (not as important) the need to replace music you already own with “purchased” music.  Whether you bought the CD or it was gifted to you, you are the *legal* owner of said music.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I've read through this at least half a dozen times now. It unfortunately contains a lot of guesswork, arm waving & 'make-it-up-as-you-go-along' with some inaccurate assertions too. I'd love to help; this seems like such a simple task, but it doesn't seem yet like you actually accurately specified the task yet. Don't tell us what you think you should be doing, tell us what you need to do.

Comment: Is the end result of this, in effect that your playlists etc are unaware anything has changed? That's actually quite tough to do. If you don't keep a myriad carefully-created playlists & are not desperately worried about all your album artwork being pristine, it could just be simpler to completely delete the old tracks before replacing.

Comment: The playlists that I are "smart" and the _manual_ process I have described preserves the metadata.  And if track XYZ is in a "regular" playlist, I would hope it is still there when the file is removed and then replaced.  After deleting the file, either "get info" or trying to play it tells you the file is not where it should be and offers you a chance to locate it—which (I hope) will update the location in the metadata and thus also repair the playlist. But I don't use any of those playlists and so I haven't tested that hypothesis.

Comment: I described the process, and the question is bolded.  If you need a rationale that's in there as well: to save disk space by replacing Apple's AAC files with MP3.

Comment: The app doesn't have a blanket refusal to play MP3.  But if an MP3 with the same metadata as an AAC was present, attempts to play the MP3 instead played the AAC.  And in one case, when the MP3 had been edited to remove a few seconds of applause and the AAC had been _removed_ but not "hidden," the AAC with the applause was streamed fro Apple's CDN.  But now the odd part: the above happened at least three times before posting the question.  But the next day, it was different.  It's still worthwhile to automate, but it didn't stream an AAC that had been removed and not hidden.

Comment: OK, so your misinformation is still the same & you've added nothing new I can work with. You're still trying to solve your solution, not the problem, Good luck.